# Why can't we measure inertia? what are the applications of inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, inertia

why there is less importance for 'inertia' in school studies...does the concept of inertia is least significant nowadays? is inertia a measurable quantity? Is there any application of inertia?

Answer (score 3):

Inertia is not actually a something in its own right. Literally it means, from Latin, the language in which Newton wrote the Principle, no-action. It is an absence of active force (as in inertial reference frame). The absence of something cannot be a measurable quantity.

There are two closely related ideas, which can be measured. Inertial mass refers to the amount of active force needed to cause a given acceleration, and Moment of inertia, which refers to the amount of torque needed to cause a given a given angular acceleration.